# Kernel freezes on loading ramdisk. How to find out what's wrong?

Tags: ubuntu, kernel, initrd

I'm using an Ubuntu Server (13.04) Minimal installation (with the Xubuntu Metapackage as a desktop environment, if that matters) on x86_64 on my Samsung notebook. I'm currently forced to use the no-longer-maintained version of the proprietary AMD graphics driver (fglrx-legacy) as the open-source "radeon" driver heats the card 15°C more in idle.

That's why I'd really like to try kernel 3.11 with the new power management features for AMD cards. The problem is, once I install a mainline kernel the system freezes after selecting the kernel in Grub with the messages:

```
Loading Linux 3.11.0-laptop ...
Loading initial ramdisk ...
```

And nothing happens. How can I find out what's wrong? Are there any logs from that early in the boot process stored somewhere?

Some more information: The system works perfectly with the Ubuntu Raring Kernel self-compiled from Git (which is based on 3.8). It doesn't work with mainline Kernel 3.9 or 3.10 (same problem). I also tried a pre-compiled "generic" version of 3.10, doesn't work either. I have 4 partitions on the hard drive: `/boot` (unencrypted), `/`, `/home` and `swap` (all LUKS/dm-crypt encrypted). The notebook is a Samsung NP-R522H. The GPU is a Mobility Radeon HD 4650.

Comment: What specific model number do you have for the Samsung laptop? Include the AMD card info too. Please add this info to your question towards the bottom.

Comment: @slm Ok, did that.

Comment: The 'initial ramdisk' is just a Linux disk image. Ungzip it, uncpio it, and look around. It's almost definitely composed entirely of shell scripts. `cat` them and find out what they do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, I totally forgot this question.

The solution back then was to use the [Saucy (Ubuntu 13.10) Kernel](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/git?p=ubuntu/ubuntu-saucy.git;a=summary), which is based on 3.11, instead of the vanilla/mainline one. Some changes probably broke compatibility, at least with my combination of hardware and software.

Answer (score 3):

#### Potential Problem?

You problem sounds like it's related to this particular issue with Samsung laptops  + UEFI + Linux.

- http://www.pcworld.com/article/2027819/not-just-linux-windows-can-brick-samsung-laptops-too.html

#### Further Research

I searched on your particular model # and did not find anything that jumped out as a potential source of your issue. So I do not think it's a widely know issue at least at this point, so your next course of action is to debug the issue.

#### Debugging a Kernel

Here are the order of things to try.

1. verbose

   During the boot phase, add the following kernel parameter to the list.

   ```
   linux ..... verbose
   ```
2. debug

   If the `verbose` argument doesn't shed any light the next level to check is `debug`.

   ```
   linux ..... debug
   ```
3. others

   There are several levels beyond that, but let's not get ahead of ourselves. Let's try the above first and see if they show where the Kernel is hanging.

#### References

- [kernel parameters](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/kernel-parameters.txt)
- [ArchLinux Boot Debugging Wiki Tips](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Boot_Debugging)

Comment: @phoenixyz - see updates for things to try.